# Delete a Library, cannot delete Folder in Raspbian File Manager

Tags: arduino, raspbian, arduino-ide

I accidentally pasted a **Tool** folder (https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder) into my Arduino **Library** folder, it is now a subfolder in my Libraries directory. See screenshot below.

Arduino throws an error with every script telling me that the "library" is incorrect, missing the .h file - because its a **TOOL**, not a **LIBRARY**, and its in the wrong location.

When I go into File Manger to either delete the folder or move it into the Libraries folder, Edit - CUT and Edit-Move to Trash are grayed out.  Right clicking this folder from the Tree doesn't allow me to delete it either, same with delete key.

I have deleted the files within this folder, but the empty folder is still in my Library folder, and I'm still getting errors in Arduino IDE.\

How do i delete this now empty sub-folder from the Library folder? Screenshot here:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxSgm.png)

I have exited the IDE and even rebooted, but still cant delete this folder.

Comment: I would suggest uninstalling Arduino and re installing it because then you know for sure it's in a valid known state and don't waste time in the future. If you really want to delete the folder you can try `sudo rm -rf /folder-name`

Comment: Thanks for that code, but unfortunately it did not delete the folder.  I even made a "Test" folder on my desktop, which was deleted succesfully using your code, but it did not delete this empty Tool folder.

Comment: Could it be a symlink, more info here: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-remove-symbolic-links-in-linux/